# pullback of sheaves from reduced schemes

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a non reduced noetherian scheme. Is there a way to recognize or characterize the coherent sheaves $\mathcal E$ on $X$ such that there exist a reduced noetherian scheme $Y$, a morphism $f:X\to Y$ and a coherent torsion free sheaf $\mathcal F$ on $Y$ such that $f^*({\mathcal F})\simeq\mathcal E$ ?

Comment: If there is a closed embedding $i \colon X \to Y$ into a reduced noetherian scheme $Y$ then you can take $F = i_*E$.

Comment: @Sasha you are right. I have modified my question by asking for a torsion free sheaf $\mathcal F$